# How to prevent Nautilus from automatically extracting ZIP files on open

Tags: nautilus, archive, zip

Upgrading from 22.04 to 23.10 I noticed that now in nautilus when I double click on a zip file it will automatically extract it in the current folder.

This is really bad when I can have a multiple-GB zip file with a lot of content and I only need a single file from the archive.

Is there a way to revert to the old behavior? Meaning, after double click, a window will be open lisiting the content of the ZIP file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default action is to use the external **Archive Manager** application when you double-click a ZIP file.

However, if your setup is different, you can select a ZIP file, right-click on the file, and select the **Open With...** menu item. From the dialog box displayed, you should be able to select another application, like **Archive Manager** and select the **Always use for this file type** option at the bottom.

Please, try again after that. If there is no change, please edit your original question and insert a screenshot of the dialog mentioned in the previous paragraph.

Comment: Ah, great thanks. I didn't notice that file-roller is not installed by default any more, so Archive Manager wasn't an option when right-clicking. After sudo apt-get install file-roller the behavior is now what I desire.